# C# Sockets: 2nd (and more) users can't connect

Tags: c#, sockets

I connect to my (C#) server and from an App built in Corona SDK but for the second person can never connect.

I have tried using different IP's i.e. two cellphones with external IP's with no difference.

This is how my server listener works:

server.cs

```
void Listener()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

                foreach (var worker in workers)
                    if (worker.IsAvailable)
                    {
                        worker.ProcessNewSocket(socket);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server.Run()");
        listener.Start();
        isRunning = true;

        foreach (var worker in workers)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(worker.Run);
            t.Start();
        }

        Listener();
    }
```

ServerWorker.cs

```
public void ProcessNewSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        var pc = new PlayerClient(this);            
        sockets.Add(socket, pc);
    }

    // this method will be called in cycle
    public void Run()
    {

        while (server.IsRunning)
        {
            List<Socket> readList = sockets.Keys.ToList(); //List of sockets that have some data from client available for reading.
            List<Socket> writeList = sockets.Keys.ToList(); //List of sockets that are ready to write (send) to the client. An action was made to a table and the change was sent to PlayerClient.Write and is now stored in the queue (MemoreStream)
            List<Socket> errorList = sockets.Keys.ToList();

            if (readList.Count() != 0 || writeList.Count() != 0 || errorList.Count() != 0)
            {
                // for providing security you can use  System.Net.Security.SslStream here when read/write data,
                // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

                Socket currentSocket = null;

                // foreach socket with events
                try
                {
                    foreach (var s in readList)
                    {
                        currentSocket = s;
                        //TODO: Get the actual length of the message.
                        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                        s.Receive(data);
                        sockets[s].OnData(data);
                    }

                    foreach (var s in writeList)
                    {
                        currentSocket = s;
                        if (sockets[s].IsWriteDataAvailable())
                        {
                            s.Send(sockets[s].GetWriteBuffer());
                            sockets[s].ClearWriteBuffer();
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var s in errorList)
                    {
                        //OnError   
                    }
                }
                // we got exception, depending on the type...
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    // send client error message, this is not always possible(for example network failure)
                    // maybe we would like to notify his opponent about connection failure
                    // terminate connection

                    if (ex.ErrorCode == (int)SocketError.ConnectionAborted || ex.ErrorCode == (int)SocketError.ConnectionReset)
                        RemoveSocket(currentSocket);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Other problem .. " + ex.ErrorCode.ToString());
                }
            }

        }    

    }
```

I'm new in network programming so I'm not really sure what to do. I have read about using ASync but first I would like to know if there is something I can do with this code and/or if I should change it completely?

Comment: Are you sure the second connection is failing to connect? Or are they both ending up connected but your attempts to send data are failing? I'm not sure what your worker threads were intended to do but from my reading, it'll just sit blocked waiting for the first socket to send it some data before it does anything else (the *comments* for `readList` talk about selecting sockets that have data available, but no such check is evident in the code)

Comment: That seems to be correct. The plan was the each ServerWorker should be able to contain X number of Sockets but it seems that it can only contain one now but when I create several ServerWorkers I can connect with the 2nd app properly. I need to find a way to solve this but that is the right answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "BREAK" statement in your Listener() Block;

```
           foreach (var worker in workers)

           if (worker.IsAvailable)
                {
                    worker.ProcessNewSocket(socket);
                    break; // this BREAK WILL END YOUR loop AFTER first CLIENT FOUND.
                }
```

So, try removing break as;

```
           foreach (var worker in workers)
           {
              if (worker.IsAvailable)
               {    
                    worker.ProcessNewSocket(socket);
               }
           }
```

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately. Also worker.IsAvailable is just a stub for the moments which returns true so it will always use the first ServerWorker ("worker") available.

Comment: Hmmm.. :(  Will you please post whole code in PEST BIN or some where and share link here...